# Update all links on page before returning page to client

Tags: asp.net, webforms

**Overview**

We have an in house CMS that we've recently added multilingual support to. The CMS allows dragging/dropping of various panels (.net controls) and some panels show dynamic content entered via a rich text editor. Also, some fields are multilingual so some panel content will change according to the current language.
Ideally we want to add the language to the URL. So `/contact-us` becomes `/en/contact-us`.
Our main handler will then set the language and the all panels will show relevant copy.

**Goal**

So, ideally we'd like to be able to:

1. Process the page server side after it's been built by our main page assembler (eg in PreRender)
2. Parse the built page or recurse the control tree to update ALL internal links
3. Prepend a lanauge code to all internal links on the page. (easy enough once we know where they all are)

NB: Some links will by in .net HyperLink controls but others will be `<a>` tags entered via a Rich Text Editor.

**Stuff I've looked at**

I've skimmed google but haven't found anything that seems to match our needs:

- Html Agility Pack - can be used to take a URL and parse for links. But I'm guessing this can't be used say in Pre_Render of our main page builder. Ideal for scraping I suppose.
- Various JS solutions - locate links and update. Very easy but I'm wary of using JS for updating URLs client side.

All suggestions welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by overriding Page.Render() as follows:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter)
{
    StringBuilder ThisSB = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter ThisSW = new StringWriter(ThisSB);
    HtmlTextWriter RenderedPage = new HtmlTextWriter(ThisSW);

    // pass our writer to base.Render to generate page output
    base.Render(RenderedPage);

    // get rendered page as a string
    string PageResult = ThisSB.ToString();

    // modify the page
    string ModifiedPage = UpdatePage(PageResult);

    // write modified page to client
    htmlWriter.Write(ModifiedPage);
}
```

The method UpdatePage can manipulate the page as a string in any way you wish - in our case we use find and update all links and local file paths.

Answer (score 0):

So, There will be dynamic content and static content. And the CMS users should be able to edit both of them. You should have a Language DB table, and for instance; For "about us" page, There should be about-us EN, about-us DE, about-us FR rows in other table.

And you should have another table for static content. For instance for contacy us form. There are static texts on contact forms. Name, e-mail,message etc.

Comment: thanks for the reply but we have the architecture (CMS + DB) complete. What we're after is a way of updating all page links (to add current language) after .net has built hte page but before it's sent to the client.